# XML Transform set attribute on specific child element

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I'm new to XML and so far I've managed to muddle along reading a few things and looking at answers to other peoples question but I'm stuck.

In the sample XML below and I need to transform `<value>some interesting information</value>` to be `<value web_label="3" mobile_label="3">some interesting information</value>`.
Value is variable so the correct value element is the sibling of `<name>Special Description</name>` which is constant.

```
<job>
    <job_type>job</job_type>
    <third_party_id>AA123456-AA</third_party_id>
    <custom_fields>
        <custom_field>
            <name>Date Promised</name>
            <permission>read_only</permission>
            <value>2020-01-01T00:00:00Z</value>
        </custom_field>
            <custom_field>
            <name>Work Order</name>
            <permission>read_only</permission>
            <value>L1</value>
        </custom_field>
        <custom_field>
            <name>Special Description</name>
            <permission>read_only</permission>
            <value>some interesting information</value>
        </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
</job>
```

In my trial and error I've managed to set the attributes on all the value elements using the below.
I thought I could then replace `match="/job/custom_fields/custom_field/value` with `match="/job/custom_fields/custom_field[name=Special Description]/value"` to select the specific element but that errors.

Is there an xpath query I can use to achieve this/what is the best way to do this in my transform?

```
    <xsl:template match="/job/custom_fields/custom_field/value">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="web_label">3</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="mobile_label">3</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

The XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
                indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/job/custom_fields/custom_field[name=Special Description]/value">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="web_label">3</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="mobile_label">3</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="custom_fields">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">array</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="third_party_id">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="web_label">2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="mobile_label">2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to modify a specific `value` element, match it using a [*predicate*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="custom_field[name='Special Description']/value">
    <value web_label="3" mobile_label="3">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
    </value>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you this got me there, using above matches the right element but in the transformed XML I ended up with `<value xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" web_label="3"mobile_label="3">some interesting information</value>`.  Combing your match with `<xsl:copy>` and `<xsl:attribute>` from my original transform got me the result I was looking for `<value web_label="3" mobile_label="3">some interesting information</value>`

Comment: I think you are mistaken - but you are obviously doing some things that are beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Sorry to be clear, when I use the XSLT exactly as you have provided this doesn't appear but when I add `<xsl:template match="custom_field[name='Special Description']/value"><value web_label="3" mobile_label="3"><xsl:value-of select="."/></value></xsl:template>` to my XSLT it shows up.  It must be something to do with "xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" in the beginning of my XLST, I'm guessing I could actually remove this, it's something I picked up from one of the examples I came across when I started composing the transform.

Comment: If you don't need it, then you should definitely remove it. And you certainly do not need to use `xsl:attribute` to add attributes with hardcoded name and value.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @michael.hor257 for suggesting

> ```
> <xsl:template match="custom_field[name='Special Description']/value">
>    <value web_label="3" mobile_label="3">
>        <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
>    </value>
> </xsl:template>
> ```

For some reason when used in my existing XSLT I ended up with `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` in the transformed XML.

```
<job>
    <job_type>job</job_type>
    <third_party_id web_label="2" mobile_label="2">AA123456-AA</third_party_id>
    <custom_fields type="array">
        <custom_field>
            <name>Date Promised</name>
            <permission>read_only</permission>
            <value>2020-01-01T00:00:00Z</value>
        </custom_field>
            <custom_field>
            <name>Work Order</name>
            <permission>read_only</permission>
            <value>L1</value>
        </custom_field>
        <custom_field>
            <name>Special Description</name>
            <permission>read_only</permission>
            <value xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                web_label="3"
                mobile_label="3">some interesting information</value>
        </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
</job>
```

Using @michael.hor257's xpath query with xsl:copy and xsl:attribute from my original XSLT however did the trick, so I ended up with:

```
    <xsl:template match="custom_field[name='Special Description']/value">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="web_label">3</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="mobile_label">3</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Resulting complete XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"
                indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="custom_field[name='Special Description']/value">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="web_label">3</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="mobile_label">3</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="custom_fields">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">array</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="third_party_id">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="web_label">2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="mobile_label">2</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the transformed XML looks like this:

```
<job>
    <job_type>job</job_type>
    <third_party_id web_label="2" mobile_label="2">AA123456-AA</third_party_id>
    <custom_fields type="array">
        <custom_field>
            <name>Date Promised</name>
            <permission>read_only</permission>
            <value>2020-01-01T00:00:00Z</value>
        </custom_field>
            <custom_field>
            <name>Work Order</name>
            <permission>read_only</permission>
            <value>L1</value>
        </custom_field>
        <custom_field>
            <name>Special Description</name>
            <permission>read_only</permission>
            <value web_label="3" mobile_label="3">some interesting information</value>
        </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
</job>
```